# Delete Unused Profile 1 from Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, user-profiles

I am required to use Edge at work. (For the record, I hate it!)

I have my profile set up in Edge. It works, and until recently was seamless.

This week I had to explore a second user profile. I set up the profile in Edge, logged in, did what I needed to do, logged out.

Then I went to Edge Settings, selected the unwanted profile and removed it. Just to be sure, I went to Windows Settings, Accounts, Email & accounts, and removed the unwanted account from there too.

Now, whenever I start Edge it presents me with a choice of profiles: firstly an empty, never used `Profile 1`, and secondly, my work profile I actually want to use. Before I can get in I have to select my work profile.
[image]
This is a work computer. I will never want a personal profile on this computer. It's unlikely I'll need a second profile again, even for testing. I just want to remove the spurious `Profile 1` and have Edge default to my work profile as it always did.

I can't delete `Profile 1` from Edge Settings. I can't delete it from Windows Settings.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I am my company IT. I don't know the answer.

Comment: @CatchAsCatchCan - What is the directory for the profile you want to delete? It’s probably “Default”, [edit] your question, instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Ramhound I'm investigating the profiles. I believe I have a solution, so I'll post an answer. Your comment fired a train of thought. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The spurious `Profile 1` account arises from an empty profile created by Edge in the User Data folder.

I found no way within Edge to remove the profile, so I had to do it manually.

Start edge and sign in with the profile you want to preserve.
Find the profile folder from the `edge://version` page
[image]

Sign out of Edge
Use Task Manager to ensure that all instances of Edge have terminated. Stop any that are still running.

Start File Explorer and browse to the `User Data` folder in the profile path.

If your profile is in the `Default` folder, look for a folder `Profile 1` in `User Data`, copy it elsewhere and then remove it.

If your profile is in some other folder (mine was in `Profile 1`) look for `Default`, copy it elsewhere and then remove it.

If you've removed the correct profile folder Edge should now fire up and default to your preferred profile.

If you've removed the wrong profile you'll be prompted to sign in. Quit Edge, return to File Explorer and copy your backed up profile folder back to `User Data`. Copy and remove the other one - see above.